# docker and vite directory mixup

Tags: docker, vite

I'm cannot figure out where I'm going to wrong. I'm trying to run a vite react app. The dockerfile builds and gets run with docker-compose. When I open the url the docker image logs out the following error:

```
Failed to load url /src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout (resolved id: /app/src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout) in /app/src/routes/index/App.jsx. Does the file exist?
```

Locally everything works fine. Docker seems to change something with the paths.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN npm install -g yarn --force
RUN npm install -g vite
RUN yarn install --force
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 90
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom", "react-router-dom"],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") }],
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true,
    strictPort: true,
    port: 90,
  },
});
```